# AXUIElementRef and ARC - Deallocated instances and __bridge vs __bridge_transfer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, dealloc, memory-management

I get this error on an NSMutableArray:

```
  -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1006e29c0
```

It happens on this line:

```
     [_array removeAllObjects];
```

Now, I understand what the error means but not why it happens in this case.

I've added an NSLog right before the above line like so:

```
      NSLog(@"%@", [_array class]);
```

And this executes normally and with the correct behavior, this is the log:

```
 2013-03-13 11:19:27.366 App[66921:303] __NSArrayM
 2013-03-13 11:19:27.367 App[66921:303] *** -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1006e29c0
```

So right before removing it doesn't seem to be deallocated..

Even if I remove the removeAllObjects call and replace it with the below line, I still get the same error.

```
     _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

All I'm doing elsewhere in the code is calling [_array addObject:...]

_array is a strong property:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

The array is first initialized in the init method.

**EDIT**: I'm adding AXUIElementRefs to this array like so:

```
 [_array addObject:(__bridge_transfer id)elementRef];
```

I thought the __bridge_transfer brings it over to ARC and I wouldn't need to manage any of that?

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE: 
Here is a sample project: http://users.telenet.be/prullen/AXMemory.zip**

This is a working project as I'm using __bridge and not __bridge_transfer.

This project contains a simple loop that does the same thing over and over again. This is to demonstrate that with just __bridge, the AXUIElementRefs never get released. They stay in memory. That's what I see in the Instruments profiler too.  You can also see the memory usage increasing every few seconds via activity monitor.

The AXUIElementRefs were obtained via AXUIElementCopyMultipleAttributeValues - so I would assume that I would have ownership of them? Nevertheless, changing to __bridge_transfer results in the errors above.

If anyone could take a look at this and let me know what I'm doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

I get an array of properties via the following statement: (line 60).

```
         AXUIElementCopyMultipleAttributeValues(frontWindowRef, attributes,0,&attributeValues);
```

Line 110 I assign the AXUIElement (looping over the children array):

```
             element = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(childrenArrayRef, i);
```

Line 112 is where I add the AXUIElementRef to the array:

```
             [_array addObject:(__bridge id)(element)];
```

Line 36 is where I empty it if it's over 500 elements:

```
if ([_array count] > 500) {
    [_array removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: print `NSlog(@"%@", _array);` see what it says

Comment: I doubt it is the array itself. May it be that the array still contains objects. Have a look whether these objects have been released in the meantime. If the memory has been reused that was originally occupied by the object then this "Not A Type" may happen when the reference just point to something (within memory that your app owns) but not the starting address of an object.

Did you enable zombies? That may give a hint with regard to the type of object that is attempted to be released.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker: I do add AXUIElementRefs to this array like so:                 [_array addObject:(__bridge_transfer id)elementRef]; - I thought the _bridge_transfer brings it over to ARC and I wouldn't manually have to release them. Do I need to loop over the array and CFRelease each of them first?

Comment: Frankly, that is beyond my knowledge. But it indicates that the idea might be right. The issue comes though the objects within the array, not the array itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just assume that `__bridge_transfer` "brings it over to ARC and [you] wouldn't need to manage any of that". You have to understand what rights and responsibilities you had for `elementRef` at the time (which we can't tell from what you've written).

I find it's much easier to understand the bridge casts if you use the corresponding `CFBridgingRetain()` and `CFBridgingRelease()` functions.  `__bridge_transfer` is the same as `CFBridgingRelease()`. So, the question is: do you own `elementRef` at the time? Is it appropriate for you to release it?

Consider, would the following have been correct?

```
[_array addObject:(__bridge id)elementRef];
CFRelease(elementRef);
```

If not, then neither is `__bridge_transfer`.

From the nature of the error you're getting, I strongly suspect you were not entitled to release `elementRef`, so you were not entitled to tell ARC that it owns it and must release it. You have caused the `AXUIElementRef` to be over-released. You should just have used a `__bridge` cast – no "transfer" and no `CF…Release()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm obtaining the AXUIElementRefs by first getting the children of an element via AXUIElementCopyMultipleAttributeValues, then looping over the returned CFArray via CFArrayGetValueAtIndex. Since "Copy" is in the name, I assumed I had ownership? I have attached a sample project to the (updated) question, if you could please take a look that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have ownership of the array referenced by `attributeValues`, which you properly `CFRelease()` (although you don't protect against failure of `AXUIElementCopyMultipleAttributeValues()`). You have ownership of `childTitleRef` and you're failing to either transfer ownership to ARC or `CFRelease()`, so it's leaking. (By the way, one of the reasons I prefer `CFBridgingRelease()` to a `__bridge_transfer` cast is so that you can develop the pattern of thinking that `Copy` must always be balanced by `CF…Release()` of one kind or another.)

Comment: I have added the CFRelease for childTitleRef, thanks. However, it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem (entirely). When looking at it in instruments I still have 15000+ AXUIElements living and growing (1 minute passed) (checked via the leak profiler). Any other ideas? I don't think I have to add CFRelease to the other elements I convert to strings right? (titleRef, roleRef and subRoleRef) - If I do that I get bad access errors. (since I already release them via the attributeValues array presumably).

Comment: Instruments should also identify the line(s) where the leaked elements were allocated. There should be no need to guess what's happening. Instruments should be giving you all the info you need to determine it exactly, although you have to do some manual reconciliation between what it's telling you and what your code is doing. I notice that you're only releasing `appRef` if you succeed in getting the main window. Seems like you're leaking that for apps which don't have a main window. That, in turn, may retain many other objects.